# SQLite not updated using DataSet

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, dataset

I have a wpf application and I'm using SqLite as a DB. In the app I have a DataSet, I can get the table but cannot update it, it return an error:

SQLite error
near ".": syntax error

The code:

```
        try
        {
            sqlite.Open();
            DEDataSetTableAdapters.DEMainDataTableAdapter ta = new DEDataSetTableAdapters.DEMainDataTableAdapter();
            ta.Update(table);
            sqlite.Close();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Helpers.DEException.SaveException(e);
            return false;
        }
```

Is this the right way to do it and I have some syntax error, or am I on the wrong path here?

googling it found nothing similar.

Thanks

Comment: Show the complete error message.

Comment: @CL "SQLite error near ".": syntax error" is the complete message